# Wann benutzt man "laufen" und wann "rennen"?

Tags: word-choice, verb

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   *[Is there any difference between “laufen” and “rennen”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/18395/9551)*

Ein Mann geht auf einer Straße. Er muss den Bus nehmen, um zur Arbeit zu kommen.
Er hat die Uhr im Haus vergessen und weiß die Zeit nicht. Der Bus kommt, er muss sich beeilen, wenn er ihn erwischen will.

Was sagt man?

> Der Mann rennt.

oder

> Der Mann läuft.

Was passt besser, und warum?

Comment: Weswegen sollte der Teil mit der Uhr wichtig sein?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Vielleicht weil der Bus nicht vor der geplanten Abfahrtszeit wegfahren *darf* (und folglich, wie wir wissen, natürlich auch nicht *kann*). Hätte also der Mann seine Uhr dabei, könnte er sich evtl. das Rennen ersparen.

Comment: @Ingo: Ich wünschte, ich würde in einer Welt leben, in der Busse nicht vor der geplanten Abfahrtszeit abfahren könnten …

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Das kenne ich auch. Ich habe mal in einem Viertel gewohnt, wo nur alle 15 Minuten ein Bus fuhr. Mehr als einmal war ich drei Minuten vor dem Abfahrtszeitpunkt (laut Fahrplan) an der Haltestelle und musste dann mehr als 20 Minuten warten.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: 15 Minuten gehen ja noch. Ich habe das schon bei Bussen erlebt, die sonntags nur zweistündlich fuhren – wenn ich auch das Glück hatte an einer Haltestelle zu leben, wo es Alternativen gab. Aber wir schweifen ab.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ich beziehe mich im Folgenden nur auf die Verwendung von *laufen, rennen* usw., wenn es darum geht, verschiedene Formen der Bewegung zu Fuß zu unterscheiden. (*Laufen* kann auch verwendet werden, um die Bewegung zu Fuß von anderen Fortbewegungsmitteln abzugrenzen.)

Jemand *läuft,* wenn es zwischen zwei Schritten einen kurzen Zeitpunkt gibt, an dem kein Fuß Bodenkontakt hat. (Alles andere ist *Gehen).*

Jemand *rennt,* wenn er schnell läuft. Ich würde sagen, dass ein grobes Kriterium ist, dass es merkbar schneller als die minimale Laufgeschwindigkeit ist. In aller Regel wird *rennen* nur verwendet, wenn derjenige nahe an seiner persönlichen Maximalgeschwindigkeit läuft, womit einhergeht, dass man diese Geschwindigkeit nicht lange aufrechterhalten kann.

In den allermeisten Fällen wäre es also:

> Der Mann rennt, um den Bus zu bekommen.

*Laufen* würde ich hier nur in dem seltenen Fall verwenden, wenn der Mann mit langsamer Geschwindigkeit läuft, aber deutlich schneller laufen (also rennen) könnte. Vermutlich schätzt er dann, dass er, um den Bus zu bekommen, laufen muss, aber nicht zu rennen braucht.

Comment: Ich würde außerdem sagen, dass „Laufen“ etwas ist, was man leicht über lange Zeit durchhalten kann, während „Rennen“ das kurzzeitige Beschleunigen auf eine hohe Geschwindigkeit ist.

Comment: @poke: Stimmt und der Antwort hinzugefügt. Wobei das mehr oder weniger eine direkte Folge aus „persönliche Maximalgeschwindigkeit“ ist – selbst Profisportler können nur ca. 40 Sekunden rennen (nach dieser Definition von rennen).

Comment: "Lauf um Dein Leben!", Staffellauf, 100 m - Lauf und Hürdenlauf - alles Läufe bei denen alle laufen was sie können. Laufen ist einfach der umfassende Begriff, der sogar Gehen umfassen kann, wie Du ansonsten richtig bemerkt hast.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich sehe keinen Widerspruch zu meiner Antwort.

Comment: `dass man diese Geschwindigkeit nicht lange aufrechterhalten kann.` Beim Marthonlauf kann man nicht von Rennen sprechen? Marathonläufer könnten i.d.R. schneller laufen?

Comment: @userunknown: Nein, beim Marathonlauf oder Ausdauerlauf im Allgemeinen würde ich nicht von *rennen* sprechen und ich kann mich auch nicht daran erinnern, dass es als solches bezeichnet würde.

Comment: @userunknown: Du hast geschrieben: »Laufen ist einfach der umfassende Begriff, der sogar Gehen umfassen kann«. Das mag in Deutschland so, sein, aber in Österreich ist Gehen keine Form von Laufen. Wenn man sich ohne Eile in der art-üblichen Geschwindigkeit bewegt, läuft man in Österreich nicht, sondern geht. Daher gehen bei uns auch Tiere. (Der Hund geht neben seinem Herrchen, das Huhn geht über die Straße.) Und Kleinkinder lernen bei uns nicht Laufen. Sie lernen Gehen.

Answer (score 10):

"Rennen" implies a lot more speed than "laufen," which is perhaps a stroll to a medium jog. Everything above that is pretty much "rennen" (Spazieren< Laufen< <strike>Joggen<</strike> Rennen) *Wenn man rennt ist Tempo das Ziel* (like a race or catching a bus). So I'd say that if the man is about to miss his bus, *rennt er*.

Comment: I don't agree that Laufen < Joggen generally, but it depends on context and I guess personal bias. But I'm running myself and for me `joggen` is sth. rather slow/easy that many people do to lose weight or similar, while `laufen` is when you seriously run and try to get faster for the next contest

Comment: @adibender: I agree. More precisely, I perceive *joggen* as a statement of the purpose of your movement (fitness) and not about the speed.

Answer (score 10):

Just a side note but it may become relevant to people traveling to Germany where regionally *"laufen"* does not mean the same as *"rennen"* but is generally used for *"gehen"*:

> Sollen wir ein Taxi nehmen, oder wollen wir *laufen*?
>   Seit wir umgezogen sind, kann Peter zu seiner Arbeit *laufen*.

Comment: Sehr richtig! Im Schwimmbad hat der Bademeister immer "nicht laufen!" gerufen und ich habe mich immer gefragt, wie ich denn sonst von der Dusche zum Beckenrand kommen soll -- auf dem Bauch rutschend etwa? Ich bin natürlich gegangen und hab mich dabei ein bisschen rebellisch gefühlt...

Comment: Beide Beispielsätze wären in Österreich falsch. Die Alternative zum Fahren wäre bei uns nicht Laufen, sondern Gehen: *Sollen wir ein Taxi nehmen, oder **gehen** wir?* (ohne *wollen*: wir wollen nicht etwas tun, sondern wir tun es). Und: *Seit wir umgezogen sind, kann Peter zu seiner Arbeit **gehen**.*

Comment: @Robert: »Nicht laufen« bedeutet: »gehen«!

Answer (score 7):

Meiner Meinung spielt, speziell im gefragten Kontext der Aspekt der Kontrolle eine wichtige Rolle (nicht so sehr des Tempos an sich). `rennen` ist unkontrollierter als Laufen und tritt in außergewöhnlichen Situationen auf (und eher nur für kurze Zeitperioden auf).

> Der Mann musste zum Bus rennen um ihn noch zu erwischen.
>
> Er rennt um sein Leben!
>
> Lola rennt! (german movie)
>
> Die Zeit rennt mir davon und die Arbeit ist noch nicht halb fertig!

Was Tempo anbelangt, laufen z.B. auch 10km Läufer, Sprinter etc.im Wettkampf so schnell sie können, allerdings in einer kontrollierten Umgebung. Ich stimme jedoch zu, dass rennen immer `laufen` bei (subjektiv) höchstmöglichen Tempo impliziert. `laufen` ist ein sehr allgemeines Wort, welches verschiedene Geschwindigkeiten abdecken kann, je nach Kontext. Zum Beispiel könnte man statt

> Wollen wir gemächlich durch den Park laufen?

auch

> Wollen wir im Park spazieren gehen?

sagen. Oder

> Wollen wir gemütlich laufen gehen?

vs.

> Wollen wir joggen gehen?

Comment: +1 wegen "Lola rennt" 81-minutige Erklärung fürs Verb.

Comment: In einem Wettrennen rennen die Läufer um die WEtte, aber der Schnellste muss nicht am Rande seiner Möglichkeiten laufen, um das Rennen zu gewinnen, es genügt wenn er schneller rennt als der Schnellste vom Rest. Trotzdem ist es Rennen. Auch wenn man den Bus kriegen muss, muss man oft rennen - nicht in Höchstgeschwindigkeit, aber sich mehr anstrengend als locker laufend.

Comment: @adibender: Gemächlich oder gemütlich laufen kann man nur in Deutschland. In Österreich ist laufen ein Synonym für rennen und bedeutet niemals gehen. Daher kann man gemütlich gehen oder schnell laufen. aber gemütlich laufen ist wie leise brüllen.

Answer (score 6):

In Süddeutschland wird `laufen` als Synonym für `gehen` benutzt (zumindest im Kur-pfälzischen Raum, meines Wissens auch im Schwäbischen). Wenn man es also eilig hat, rennt man. Wenn nicht, läuft man.

Comment: Keineswegs allgemein in Süddeutschland. Und ich kenne diese Verwendung nur von einem Norddeutschen.

Comment: Dies gilt für die ganze Bundesrepublik.

Comment: In Süddeutschland *springst* du, wo der Hochdeutsche rennt. Wobei *springen* im Unterschied zum "rennen" auch noch das spielerische Element einfängt. Kinder, die Haschen spielen, oder Hunde, `springet` beispielsweise.

Answer (score 5):

Die anderen haben das schon gut beantwortet, man würde hier „rennen“ verwenden. Ich glaube aber, dass die Unterschiede in der Verwendung, die hier angesprochen wurden, gar nicht so sehr landschaftlich sind. Berlin liegt sicher nicht in Süddeutschland, und auch hier benutzt man „laufen“, um zu beschreiben, dass man geht, ganz besonders, wenn man es um die Abgrenzung zur Fortbewegung auf Rädern geht.

> Ich musste laufen, weil mein Auto in der Werkstatt ist.

Die Unterschiede in der Verwendung sind vor allem zwischen Läufern und Nichtläufern. Dass sich das Laufen vom Gehen durch eine Flugphase unterscheidet, wie Wrzlprmft schreibt, ist eine technische Definition, die den Wortgebrauch unter Läufern gut beschreibt. Würde mich wie in adibenders Beispiel jemand fragen, ob wir gemütlich durch den Park laufen wollen, dann wäre für mich, wenn der andere auch ein Läufer ist, ganz klar, dass er das meint, wir könnten joggen (ähem!) gehen.

Also, in der Situation hier würde wohl fast jeder sagen, dass er rennen musste, um den Bus rechtzeitig zu erreichen.

Ansonsten bezeichnet im üblichen Sprachgebrauch von Nichtläufern „laufen“ meist die Fortbewegung zu Fuß allgemein und dabei meist das Gehen. Das Training von Läufern oder ähnliche Bewegungen, die zum Erhalt der Gesundheit durchgeführt werden, würden eher als „rennen“, heutzutage aber meist als „joggen“ bezeichnet. Was Nichtläufer, die auch nicht besonders leichtathletisch interessiert sind, sagen, wenn sie einen Läufer (die offizielle Bezeichnung der leichtathletischen Disziplin ist „Lauf“, übrigens auch in Abgrenzung zum Sprint) im Wettkampf sehen, weiß ich gar nicht genau, ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass sie sagen, dass er rennt.

Läufer hingegen meinen tatsächlich meist eine Fortbewegung zu Fuß mit Flugphase, wenn sie „laufen“ sagen. Ohne Flugphase heißt es „gehen“, und das bezeichnet sowohl die Fortbewegung im Alltag als auch die leichtathletische Disziplin „Gehen“. Das zügige Spazierengehen in Sportkleidung bezeichnen sie ebenso wie Laien als „Walking“. (Ich hörte mal eine Geherin sagen: „Weil ich verletzt war, konnte ich mehrere Monate nur walken.“) Lauftraining bezeichnet der Läufer aber nicht als „joggen“, das wäre ein Sakrileg. Als „Jogging“ bezeichnet er das, was Jogger tun (zur Abgrenzung von Läufern zu Joggern schreibe ich hier lieber nichts), und vielleicht auch besonders langsames Laufen, insbesondere in den Pausen beim Intervalltraining, letzteres wird aber öfter als „Traben“ bezeichnet. Ein Laufwettkampf wird übrigens auch als „Rennen“ bezeichnet, trotzdem ist, wie adibender schon schreibt, „rennen“ als Beschreibung des Laufens während eines Rennens eher unüblich.

Es kann daher durchaus vorkommen und zu leichter Verwirrung führen, dass ein Anfänger in einem Laufforum etwas schreibt wie: „Ich konnte nicht die ganze Strecke joggen, sondern musste zwischendurch laufen.“ Das liest sich für den Läufer merkwürdig, denn für ihn ist „joggen“ ja langsamer als „laufen“.

Comment: Das es keine regionalen Unterschiede gibt kann ich so nicht nachvollziehen. In Wien heißt Laufen nie gehen, sondern immer Laufen.

Answer (score 4):

The two are interchangeable in many, but by no means all cases. As @thekeyofgb noted, there's a distinction in speed. Another crucial distinction? If it's in the sense of running as a sport, it's always *laufen* - nobody *geht rennen*, everybody *geht laufen*.

Answer (score 3):

Die [Antwort von Carsten Schultz](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9433/1224) zwingt mich gerade zu auch meinen Senf abzugeben.

Während ich in weiten Teilen zustimme, denke ich nicht, dass "Läufer" anders über das Wort *laufen* denken als "Nichtläufer". Auch würde ein "Anfänger" das Wort *laufen* nicht in seiner Bedeutung verwechseln. Vorausgesetzt, er ist der deutschen Sprache mächtig.

Je nach Kontext interpretiere ich das Wort *laufen* entweder als *gehen* oder als *~rennen* bzw. *joggen*<sup>1</sup>.

Beispiele:

> Nehmen wir den Bus oder laufen[=gehen] wir.
>   Gehen wir heute im Wald laufen[=joggen] <sub>Wollte man *gehen*, würde man *spazieren* verwenden.</sub>
>   Beim Shopping: "Kannst du nicht schneller laufen[=gehen]?"
>   Beim Sport: "Kannst du nicht schneller laufen[=rennen]?"
>   Sollen wir **laufen gehen**[=joggen]?

Die generelle Einordnung der Geschwindigkeit ist:
    *spazieren|wandern <= gehen|laufen < joggen <= laufen < rennen*

In Bezug auf eine Anpassung der Geschwindigkeit oder Vergleich dieser, gilt dann Folgendes:

- Wenn man spaziert bzw. wandert, werden ausschließlich die Begriffe *gehen* und *laufen* (im Sinne von *gehen*) verwendet. *Joggen*, *laufen*(im Sinne von *rennen*) und *rennen* stehen im absoluten Kontrast dazu, daher unangebracht:

  > Können wir etwas langsamer gehen?
  >   Laufen wir zu schnell?
- Wenn man durch die Stadt schlendert, kann *laufen* doppeldeutig verwendet werden. Zur Verdeutlichung kann *rennen* verwendet, es ist – wie oben erwähnt – aber immer klar, um welche Art von *Laufen* es sich handelt.. *Rennen* kann hier auch im Sinne von *gehen* verwendet werden, wenn es auf *besonders schnelles Gehen* Bezug nimmt:

  > Da kommt die Bahn. Komm, lauf schon. => rennen
  >   Rennt doch nicht so; wir sind doch nicht auf der Flucht. => gehen
- Wenn man *joggen* geht, ist mit *laufen* immer die schnellere Fortbewegung gemeint. Sonst spricht man von *gehen*:

  > Ich konnte nicht die ganze Strecke joggen, musste daher zwischendurch gehen.
  >   Ich konnte nicht durchgehend laufen und musste zwischenzeitlich einige Meter gehen.
- Ist das *laufen gehen* gezieltes Training (für einen Wettkampf), so spricht man von *laufen*. Sehr schnelles Laufen sind dann *Sprints*, in Verbform: *sprinten*. Hier ist es eher untypisch von *rennen* zu sprechen, ist aber möglich. Das langsame Gehen (zur Erholung) wird ausschließlich als *gehen* bezeichnet.

  > In drei Wochen laufe ich einen Marathon.
  >   Ich laufe jeden Tag 18 km. Danach gehe ich noch 2 km gemütlich.
  >   Alle zehn Minuten lege ich einen kurzen Sprint ein.

---

<sup>1</sup> Um eine ungefähre "mathematische Relation" herzustellen, sei erwähnt, dass bei langsamer, gemütlicher Fortbewegung *laufen* immer gleich *gehen* ist, während bei schneller, zügiger Fortbewegung *laufen* immer kleiner als *rennen* ist.

Comment: Hallo, ich habe noch nicht alles gelesen, mir ist aber auch aufgefallen, dass meine Antwort zumindest unvollständig war. Bei dem Satz „Mimili läuft in den Garten“ aus einer anderen Frage ist für mich eindeutig, dass sie nicht gegangen ist, was aber von meiner Antwort hier nicht erklärt wird. Dass ich im Gespräch mit Nichtläufern teils meine Wortwahl bewusst anpasse, um Missverständnisse zu vermeiden, ist aber wirklich so. Auch das Beispiel aus einem Forum am Ende meiner Antwort ist echt, wenn auch paraphrasiert. Zugegeben, das heißt nicht, dass diese Verwendung häufig ist.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Müsste man mal rausfinden, von wem das Zitat stimmt. Ich habe bewusst hinzugefügt, "dass man der deutschen Sprache mächtig sein sollte". Es gibt genug 'Kiddies' die schreiben den größten Mist in Internetforen (gilt leider auch für manche Leute, von denen man eine gewisse Reife erwartet). Anyway, was ich nur meine ist, dass sowas definitiv ein Sonderfall ist, zurückzuführen auf Unvermögen oder Schluderei. - Bzgl. Konversation mit Läufern: Ich hab einige Freunde, die Marathon laufen. Kann keinen Unterschied zu Nicht-Läufern ausmachen, was den Sprachgebrauch angeht.

Answer (score 3):

Die doch sehr langatmigen Erklärungen, kurz zusammengefaßt:

1. *laufen* natürliche Art der Fortbewegung auf den Beinen, im Gegensatz zu fahren, fliegen, reiten, usw., wobei über die Geschwindigkeit nichts ausgesagt wird. ("Lauf um dein Leben!" kann durchaus die Empfehlung sein, möglichst schnell zu rennen.)
2. *laufen* als sportliche Betätigung, wobei in Wirklichkeit gesprungen wird.

Niemals kann daher *rennen* und *laufen* verwechselt werden. Der Mann muß *rennen* um den Bus noch zu kriegen, denn, wie es mal in einem Schlager hieß, "laufen will er nicht".

Answer (score 2):

Du kannst dich nach Duden richten (hab nicht nachgeschaut) und rennen für schnelle
Bewegung nehmen, aber auch laufen.

In Süddeutschland ist laufen aber nicht rennen, sondern ganz normal gehen. Am besten verwendest du rennen für schnelle Bewegung, das ist eindeutig. Bei laufen weiß man nie so genau, meint der Sprecher gehen oder rennen. Das ergibt sich aber oft aus dem Kontext.